# HTML vector icon

Tags: html, vector, icons, figma

```html
<body>
  <div class="header-8">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h1 class="#headline.6">International Network</h1>
          <h4>We know how large objects will act, but things on a small scale</h4>
          <div class="cta">
          <button class="button.bt.primary-color.btn-round">
            Get Quote Now
          </button>
          <button class="button.bt.primary-color.btn-outline.btn-round">
            LEarn More
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col_md_4">
        <div class="card-item">
          <div class="icn resize icn-md">


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Please click the above link to view the picture.
As you can see, I am not able to find the vector icon code for my project in FIGMA.
See the left side, Vector is clicked and on the right side the icon are visible.
But I don't know what's the code for it.
Moreover, if anyone have done any FIGMA project, can you tell me that I have placed the div tags correctly in VSCODE according to the left side objects?

Comment: Since I am new here I did not know. Noted it. Thank you.

Comment: And yet you have not corrected your error. Your question is in danger of being closed. I suggest you remedy this immediately.

Answer (score 0):

By the way,you can right click the svg icon and copy as svg,or download the svg and show in your browser,check the html elements and copy the svg elements is also works
Try to find your vector icon in inspect selection,it's here:

[image: inspect]

Comment: This inspect option is not showing the icon code here, it' showing CSS properties.